# How to quantize my tensorflow model without using bazel ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel

I am trying to quantize my tensorflow trained graph (.pb file) and following these instructions in the [TF tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization)  . But they are using bezel commands to build it . Is there any way where I can run this as a normal python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's designed to be run through Bazel.  It's possible you could manually compile all the protos, add `__init__.py` files in the directories, and create any generated files, but it'll probably be a lot easier to just download the [Bazel binary](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.5.3) for your system.

Comment: Yeah. I will use bazel . Here I should install TF from sources in-order to run this right ?

Comment: Yes, you probably just need to run `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git; cd tensorflow; ./configure`.